# Webmin support for Firewalld

Tags: firewalld, webmin

I have configured routers/firewalls several times in the past with nftables.  I'm now setting up a Linux router that will be managed by other people with less experience, so I figured Webmin would be a good choice.

I'm having trouble correlating what the UI presents with the requirements of setting up a router/firewall. Some things seem to be missing from the UI:

- Configuring rules for incoming vs outgoing connections. The UI just defines zones and rules with no provision for specifying direction.
- Configuration for NAT seems to be missing completely.
- What to do with unnecessary zones. If I choose "Selected interfaces" and then uncheck all interfaces and apply, it reverts to "All interfaces". Is the intent here just to delete any zones you're not using?

Question: Am I missing something basic about Webmin's UI for firewalld, or is it only a partial implementation?

Comment: IMHO on Debian 11 - It seems, that webmin still can not handle `nftables` in 2023.05 but reverting to `iptables-legacy`, causing trouble. So yes, `firewalld` seems to be a good choice at first site, but **be warned** : `apt install firewalld` completely locked out of my system, so do no start installing from SSH login! (because it will be terminated during install and probably cause a half-install with broken rule setup.)

Comment: Almost a year and still no answer. Not surprised at all. Yes, Webmin just locked me completely out of my system, too, and apparently not wanting my local network to be 100% locked out of my innternal server is such an abstruse request that there is no documentation or discussion about it anywhere on the internet about how to avoid it. I've been looking for about 3 hours now.  My recommendation: never install webmin.  Looks like I'm back to my fourth clean OS reinstall in 2 days.

Comment: @johnsmith FWIW, I gave up on a home-brew router/firewall and went with pfSense (the open source version) running on a mini-PC with an Intel(R) Celeron(R) J4125 CPU @ 2.00GHz.  There are lots of very inexpensive choices ($100-200) out there.  The UI is quite good and it does the job very well.  Gigabit fiber doesn't seem to challenge the processor at all, if you're going higher speeds you _might_ need to do some benchmarking.